# Do I really have to pass the session as a param when doing Mongo Node transaction

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-nodejs-driver

When doing a transaction like

```js
await ( await this.client )
 .withSession(async (session) => {
    try {
      session.startTransaction();
      await collection1.updateMany({ id }, { $set: { done: true } }, { session });
      await collection2.updateMany({ someId, test: { $exists: true } }, { $set: { test: [] } }, { session });
      session.commitTransaction();
    } catch (err) {
      session.abortTransaction();
      throw new Error(`Failed`);
    }
 });
```

Why do I have to pass the { session } as a param for the 2 updates?

The documentation doesn't seem to explain why that is, shouldn't everything between a start, stop session use that session, including await.collection1?

Thank you

Comment: How would the `updateMany` function know that it should run within the transaction otherwise?

Comment: That is why we do a star/stop transaction "block", should also be smart enough to know what session I want to use since I started a new one a few lines above.

Should everything withing run on the same section/transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is totally normal in all the DBMS that i worked with.
As far as i know, the reason behind that is that you dont always want to add every DB-transaction to the started Transaction, because it might lead to reduced throughput and blocking.

So you only want to add Transactions that change the state of a Document and which are essential. E.g. most of the time you dont want to add simple read operations to the transactions and block the document with that

Comment: I do get you want to run some on a different session sometimes but why do I have to specifically mention which session and if I don't, what is the default session, and will all queries use the same session, or are new ones opened?

PHP/MYSQL seem not to need a session, anyway I should read the docs again, maybe I missed something

Comment: PHP/MYSQL seem to do the same, maybe I was using an ORM that did not require a session to be set.

Comment: Well you dont have to use a specified transaction in mongodb. You can also just do a DB operation without a transaction. These ACID transactions should prevent data inconsistency, so if you have a simple read operation of data that doesnt change by the write transactions, there is no need to put that DB operation into any transactions, since you would only block a document and slow down the process.

And a session isnt a connection. So by deault DB operations are just handled over the connection to the DB without a session.

Comment: Ok, makes more sense, thank you